# How to get right Map for India in highcharts?

Tags: r, highcharts, maps

I am working on covid dataset and have mapped the data on **Indian Map** using **highcharts** but that **Map** is not latest & **doesn't show all its States** - for example **Telengana** which was formed ~7 years back is missing in the map.

Highchart Map link: https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/in/in-all

[image]

```
hcmap(
            "countries/in/in-all",
            data = (df_ind %>% filter(Date == max(Date, na.rm = TRUE),
                                      State.UnionTerritory != "India"
            )
            ),
            value = Daily_confirmed,
            joinBy = c("hc-a2"),
            datalabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = "{point.name}"),
            borderColor = "#FAFAFA",
            borderWidth = 0.1,
            tooltip = list(
                # valueDecimals = 2,
                # valuePrefix = "$"
            )
        ) %>% 
            hc_colorAxis(minColor = "midnightblue", maxColor = "orange")
```

I did find another Map of India on highcharts containing **State - Telengana** but whenever I use that all the mapped data on it gets messed up:

https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/
https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/in/custom/in-all-disputed.svg

**"countries/in/custom/in-all-disputed"**

[image]

If I use this link & check `hc-a2` field then turns out that State `Chandigarh` & `Chattisgarh` have same `CH`value in `hc-a2`.

```
hc-a2  n
<chr>  <int>
    
AP  2           
CH  2           
DA  2           
MA  2           
PU  2
```

Basically there are issues with the mapping data which I can change it now manually or may be re map it by using names but this will not be good for future use as I may need to change it everytime.

So is there a more consistent form of **Map for India in highcharts** that I can refer to ??

Comment: Looks like a bug. hc-a2 is not unique for that map, but this could be fixed. Here is an issue that looks related: https://github.com/highcharts/map-collection-dist/issues/46#issuecomment-718721435
Report the problems there as a new comment or as a new issue (if your problem is not directly related to the linked issue) and I will prepare a fixed map for you as a workaround.

Comment: Hi @KacperMadej, thanks for sharing the link and yes it indeed is relevant. I also had a look at map on `https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jaL7q5x3/1` from the comments and this seems more relevant as it has latest updated State "Ladakh` but I am unable to use this weblink inside the `hcmap()`. Please let me know how can I use the latest map from this link or a new fixed map which includes both States `Ladakh & Telengana` would also be great. I have commented on the same github link as you have provided above.