# How to convert HTML into dataframe by using json with either r or python?

Tags: python, html, r, json

I am creating a `map` and its data seems to be available in `html` on this weblink: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jaL7q5x3/2/

(I am not really a programmer so not sure if that's **html or java or json** but it says **html** so taking it as **html** but it looks **java/json** to me)

As I am unable to use this directly into `highcharts` `hcmap()` function from **r library**. So, I tried to copy & paste this `html` into a `.txt` file and tried to read it in `python` as `json` object so that I can convert it into a `dataframe` object but it failed.

```
with open('E:/3. R/Covid19/path.txt') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
```

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 48 column 23 (char 56995)

Is there a way I can **read** this & convert it into a **dataframe** which I can use further to create `map` ?

I am open to both **r & python** solutions for converting this into an object which can be **converted into dataframe**.

Small Part of code on website:

> Highcharts.maps["countries/in/custom/in-all-disputed"] =
> {"title":"India with disputed
> territories","version":"1.1.3","type":"FeatureCollection","copyright":"Copyright
> (c) 2020 Highsoft AS, Based on
> [http://projects.datameet.org/maps/states/","copyrightShort":"projects.datameet.org","copyrightUrl":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/in/","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:32644"}},"hc-transform":{"default":{"crs":"+proj=utm](http://projects.datameet.org/maps/states/%22,%22copyrightShort%22:%22projects.datameet.org%22,%22copyrightUrl%22:%22https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/in/%22,%22crs%22:%7B%22type%22:%22name%22,%22properties%22:%7B%22name%22:%22urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:32644%22%7D%7D,%22hc-transform%22:%7B%22default%22:%7B%22crs%22:%22+proj=utm)
> +zone=44 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs","scale":0.00020862025385,"jsonres":15.5,"jsonmarginX":-999,"jsonmarginY":9851,"xoffset":-814534.248882,"yoffset":4122045.33412}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"Madhya
> Pradesh","properties":{"hc-group":"admin1","hc-key":"madhya
> pradesh","hc-a2":"MP","name":"Madhya
> Pradesh","hc-middle-x":0.5,"hc-middle-y":0.5},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[977,4582],[974,4582],[971,4589],[976,4590],[977,4582]]],[[[3557,4938],[3575,4908],[3575,4899],[3575,4899],[3575,4898],[3576,4897],[3578,4895],[3579,4896],[3580,4897],[3580,4898],[3583,4896],[3584,4895],[3646,4865],[3624,4785],[3565,4775],[3566,4732],[3509,4702],[3515,4664],[3509,4657],[3467,4607],[3411,4565],[3386,4547],[3361,4576],[3317,4562]

**My original SO post relevant to this which still remains unanswered:**

[How to get r highchart map data from website instead of hcmap()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67710864/how-to-get-r-highchart-map-data-from-website-instead-of-hcmap)

[How to get right Map for India in highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67619571/how-to-get-right-map-for-india-in-highcharts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are looking to extract is JSON data. It is however not completely valid JSON. You'll have to clean it up a little bit. You can use sites like [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate JSON data.

The issues with the JSON data are (1) at the beginning, you need to remove the part that says "Highcharts.maps["countries/in/custom/in-all-disputed"] =" up until the first curly bracket `{`; (2) three lines have a "comment" with two slashes followed by four digits, like this "// 0000". These need to be removed before ingesting the JSON data (I see "// 8440" twice and "// 1227" once).

After doing this you can extract the data from the txt file in `R` with the `jsonlite` package.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tibble)
a <- fromJSON("path.txt")
as_tibble(a$features)
#> # A tibble: 37 x 4
#>    type   id       properties$`hc-g… $`hc-key`   $`hc-a2` $name   $`hc-middle-x`
#>    <chr>  <chr>    <chr>             <chr>       <chr>    <chr>            <dbl>
#>  1 Featu… Madhya … admin1            madhya pra… MP       Madhya…           0.5 
#>  2 Featu… Uttar P… admin1            uttar prad… UP       Uttar …           0.5 
#>  3 Featu… Karnata… admin1            karnataka   KA       Karnat…           0.35
#>  4 Featu… Nagaland admin1            nagaland    NA       Nagala…           0.5 
#>  5 Featu… Bihar    admin1            bihar       BI       Bihar             0.5 
#>  6 Featu… Lakshad… admin1            lakshadweep LA       Laksha…           0.5 
#>  7 Featu… Andaman… admin1            andaman an… AA       Andama…           0.5 
#>  8 Featu… Assam    admin1            assam       AS       Assam             0.5 
#>  9 Featu… West Be… admin1            west bengal WB       West B…           0.6 
#> 10 Featu… Puduche… admin1            puducherry  PY       Puduch…           0.62
#> # … with 27 more rows, and 1 more variable: geometry <df[,2]>
```

Comment: Thanks @Till after trying my hands in `R` for `json` I spend good time in `python` to convert it. I am glad this could work in `r` itself. Thanks alot, really appreciate your help & effort :))